# How does one create and use a global utility module?

Tags: python

I want to create a globally accessible module with utility methods and classes. It will be used in various projects, so I don't want the module to be specific to any one project. Obviously I could copy the directory into each new project, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. What's the best practice for something like this?

Comment: why not import?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: you could upload your module to pypi or another package repository and then just pull it from there. though from what you are talking about it sounds like what you want is to make it a submodule. look up git submodules. that is prolly your best bet

Comment: Probably not pythonic, but I created a module for importing and just placed it in a folder, and added the folder onto my PATH environment (because I'm lazy).  The more pythonic way to do that however, is to properly create and install your own module under the proper Python lib path (e.g. `lib/site-packages`)

Comment: A quick-n-dirty way is just to put/copy your module into the `Python/Lib/site-packages` directory. To be a little more formal, you could write a `setup.py` script for your module that did this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way of handling this would be to use `pip` to install your package in each of the virtual environments you use. If you aren't yet using virtualenvs, then you can make a module or package available by installing it in your Python interpreter's *site-packages* directory.

There are a number of complexities you would have to battle with to make your package pip-installable, so you will be relieved to know that for many purposes it's enough simply to copy the module into *site-packages*.

If you aren't familiar enough with your Python installation to know where *site-packages* lives, the following snippet might help:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...   print(p)
...

/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/general/lib/python36.zip
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/general/lib/python3.6
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/general/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/general/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/general/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa
>>>
```